# The difference of running sqlite using "sqlite3" and "rails db"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'd like to know the difference of running sqlite using "sqlite3" and "rails db".

`rails db`:

```
User-Mini-4:commandsapp user$ rails db
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

`sqlite`:

```
User-Mini-4:commandsapp user$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between two commands, `sqlite3` and `rails db`, is that `sqlite3` calls the SQLite explicitly, unlike, `rails db`, the same as `rails dbconsole`, which calls the database implicitly, as it pertains to how you configured it in your `config/database.yml`.

*How does this differ?*

`sqlite3` runs a default SQLite session that uses in-memory database, not a file on disk, and so all changes will be lost when the session exits.

See more - https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

`rails db` figures out which database you're using and drops you into whichever command line interface you would use with it (and figures out the command line parameters to give to it, too!).

See more - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-dbconsole

Comment: Thanks a lot!.
And with this, I found out that
  $ rails db
is the same as
  $ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3